# Use pathlib for S3 paths

Tags: python, pathlib

I would like to build some functionality to move files between S3 and my local file system, but `pathlib` appears to combine repeated slashes, breaking my aws-cli functionality:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> str(Path('s3://loc'))
s3:/loc'
```

How can I manipulate S3 paths in this way?

Comment: For what it's worth there is ongoing effort for URI support in stdlib's Path, which should open a path for supporting various URIs https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/107465

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try combining [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
from pathlib import PosixPath

s3_url = urlparse('s3://bucket/key')
s3_path = PosixPath(s3_url.path)
s3_path /= 'hello'
s3_new_url = urlunparse((s3_url.scheme, s3_url.netloc, s3_path.as_posix(), s3_url.params, s3_url.query, s3_url.fragment))
# or
# s3_new_url = s3_url._replace(path=s3_path.as_posix()).geturl()
print(s3_new_url)
```

It's quite cumbersome, but it's what you asked for.

Comment: NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system. Window user should use PurePosixPath instead.

Comment: When dealing with S3 paths, it's important to note that they use a different escaping method than POSIX paths. For example, if you have a folder name with a space in it, you'd use "%20" instead of a backslash like in POSIX paths. Due to these differences, it's recommended to use Urllib instead f Pathlib for S3 paths.

Answer (score 22):

### Using `s3path` package

The [`s3path`](https://github.com/liormizr/s3path) package makes working with S3 paths a little less painful. It is installable from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/s3path/) or [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/s3path). Use the `S3Path` class for actual objects in S3 and otherwise use `PureS3Path` which shouldn't actually access S3.

Although the [previous answer by metaperture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954824/_) did mention this package, it didn't include the URI syntax.

Also be aware that this package has certain deficiencies which are reported in its issues.

```py
>>> from s3path import PureS3Path

>>> PureS3Path.from_uri('s3://mybucket/foo/bar') / 'add/me'
PureS3Path('/mybucket/foo/bar/add/me')

>>> _.as_uri()
's3://mybucket/foo/bar/add/me'
```

Note the instance relationships to `pathlib`:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path, PurePath
>>> from s3path import S3Path, PureS3Path

>>> isinstance(S3Path('/my-bucket/some/prefix'), Path)
True
>>> isinstance(PureS3Path('/my-bucket/some/prefix'), PurePath)
True
```

### Using `pathlib.Path`

This is a lazier version of the answer by kichik using only `pathlib`. This approach is not necessarily recommended. It's just not always entirely necessary to use `urllib.parse`.

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> orig_s3_path = 's3://mybucket/foo/bar'
>>> orig_path = Path(*Path(orig_s3_path).parts[1:])
>>> orig_path
PosixPath('mybucket/foo/bar')

>>> new_path = orig_path / 'add/me'
>>> new_s3_path = 's3://' + str(new_path)
>>> new_s3_path
's3://mybucket/foo/bar/add/me'
```

### Using `os.path.join`

For simple joins only, how about [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)?

```py
>>> import os

>>> os.path.join('s3://mybucket/foo/bar', 'add/me')
's3://mybucket/foo/bar/add/me'
>>> os.path.join('s3://mybucket/foo/bar/', 'add/me')
's3://mybucket/foo/bar/add/me'
```

Windows users can apply `.replace(os.sep, '/')` for platform safety.

[`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) cannot however be naively used:

```py
>>> os.path.normpath('s3://mybucket/foo/bar')  # Converts 's3://' to 's3:/'
's3:/mybucket/foo/bar'
```

Comment: A note about `os.path.join`: "If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components will be discarded." so you may want to `.lstrip("/")` your arguments.

Comment: os.path.join uses "\\" on Windows, so this won't work

Comment: @Stefan A note has now been added for Windows users.

Comment: The point of os.path.join is to have os-dependent path joining. So even if you fix the outcome of it, using it here is miscommunicating intent, as the joining mechanism here should be os-independent.

Answer (score 4):

## Using `cloudpathlib`

Wanted to add this as another option that has nice caching and transparent read/write access in addition the the standard path manipulations.

The [`cloupathlib`](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/) package provides [pathlib methods support](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/#supported-methods-and-properties) for S3 paths in addition to Google Cloud Storage and Azure Blob Storage.

For example:

```py
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath
from itertools import islice

ladi = CloudPath("s3://ladi/Images/FEMA_CAP/2020/70349")

ladi.parent
#> S3Path('s3://ladi/Images/FEMA_CAP/2020')

ladi.bucket
#> 'ladi'

# list first 5 images for this incident
for p in islice(ladi.iterdir(), 5):
    print(p)
#> s3://ladi/Images/FEMA_CAP/2020/70349/DSC_0001_5a63d42e-27c6-448a-84f1-bfc632125b8e.jpg
#> s3://ladi/Images/FEMA_CAP/2020/70349/DSC_0002_a89f1b79-786f-4dac-9dcc-609fb1a977b1.jpg
#> s3://ladi/Images/FEMA_CAP/2020/70349/DSC_0003_02c30af6-911e-4e01-8c24-7644da2b8672.jpg
#> s3://ladi/Images/FEMA_CAP/2020/70349/DSC_0004_d37c02b9-01a8-4672-b06f-2690d70e5e6b.jpg
#> s3://ladi/Images/FEMA_CAP/2020/70349/DSC_0005_d05609ce-1c45-4de3-b0f1-401c2bb3412c.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a module that subclasses pathlib.Path for s3 paths: https://pypi.org/project/s3path/

Usage:

```py
>>> from s3path import S3Path

>>> bucket_path = S3Path('/pypi-proxy/')
>>> [path for path in bucket_path.iterdir() if path.is_dir()]
[S3Path('/pypi-proxy/requests/'),
 S3Path('/pypi-proxy/boto3/'),
 S3Path('/pypi-proxy/botocore/')]

>>> boto3_package_path = S3Path('/pypi-proxy/boto3/boto3-1.4.1.tar.gz')
>>> boto3_package_path.exists()
True
>>> boto3_package_path.is_dir()
False
>>> boto3_package_path.is_file()
True

>>> botocore_index_path = S3Path('/pypi-proxy/botocore/index.html')
>>> with botocore_index_path.open() as f:
>>>     print(f.read())
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Package Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="botocore-1.4.93.tar.gz">botocore-1.4.93.tar.gz</a><br>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  `pathlib` is for *filesystem* paths (i.e., paths to files on your computer), while S3 paths are URIs.

Comment: [heres](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-March/039268.html) a discussion about adding URI functionality to the pathlib module some day.

Answer (score 1):

Pathy is pretty great for this:
https://github.com/justindujardin/pathy

It uses Smart open under the hood to provide file access to bucket storage, and so is better than s3path for this reason.

You can use `Pathy.fluid` to make apis that work on both local files and files in bucket storage

```py
from pathlib import BasePath
from pathy import Pathy, FluidPath

def process_f(f: Union[Union[str, Pathy, BasePath]):
    path = Pathy.fluid(f)
    # now you have a Pathlib you can process that's local or in s3/GCS
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jwodder answer, that pathlib is for fs path only. However, out of curiosity, I played a bit with inheritance from pathlib.Path and received quite a viable solution.

```
import pathlib


class S3Path(pathlib.PosixPath):
    s3_schema = "s3:/"

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args[0].startswith(cls.s3_schema):
            args = (args[0].replace(cls.s3_schema, "", 1),) + args[1:]
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return self.s3_schema + self._str
        except AttributeError:
            self._str = (
                self._format_parsed_parts(
                    self._drv,
                    self._root,
                    self._parts,
                )
                or "."
            )
            return self.s3_schema + self._str


def test_basic():
    s3_path_str: str = "s3://some/location"
    s3_path = S3Path(s3_path_str)
    assert str(s3_path) == s3_path_str

    s3_path_1 = s3_path / "here"
    assert str(s3_path_1) == s3_path_str + "/here"

    assert s3_path.parent == S3Path("s3://some")
```

The advantage of it is that you don't need any pip install dependency. Plus you could easily adopt it to any other URI like paths, for example hdfs

Answer (score 0):

It's useful and simple to extend the str class to handle this

```
class URL(str):
  def __truediv__(self, val):
    return URL(self + '/' + val)
```

an example usage would be `URL('s3://mybucket') / 'test'` → `"s3://mybucket/test"`